# Rails Postgres hstore. DB not being updated with changed values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to understand how to use hstore and it seems the database isn't updated if I try to modify a value in my hash.

In my rails console I do

```
u = User.new
u.hash_column = {'key' => 'first'}
u.save
```

I get a message in my console
 (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "hash_column" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE ...
  (18.0ms) COMMIT
and when I check in the DB the column has the correct data

now when I try

```
u.hash_column['key'] = 'second'
```

the model seems correct in the console

```
puts u.hash_column
```

gives
    {"key"=>"second"}

however when I try to save this
    u.save
in my console I just get
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
with no update statement and when I check the DB the data hasn't changed.

if I change another attribute on the user model and save it hash_column still doesn't get updated. The only way I can change the hash_column in the database seems to be to assign to the complete hash like

```
u.hash_column = {'key' => 'second'}
```

is this how it is meant to work or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is due to the way that rails currently tracks changes. It will only track changes when you use the attributes setter (`u.hash_column`). If you update a value in the hash, you have to notify Rails that the value changed by calling `u.hash_column_will_change!`. This marks the value as dirty and the next time save is called, it will be persisted.

This also effects arrays and strings and dates. If you call `u.string_value.gsub!` or `u.array_column << value` those changes will not be persisted without calling the `<column>_will_change!` method for those columns